# set height of specific row in css-grid

Tags: css, css-grid

Let say I have many many rows, I don't know how many I have but I know they have all the same height, except one because it's a divider. I want all the rows to be 40px height, but the divider being 15px, and I don't know exactly where is the divider, how can I do ?

I know I can use `grid-auto-rows: 40px` for all the rows, but for the particular divider `div`, when I define a height it doesn't affect the `row`.

Comment: Post your code so we can reproduce the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This is probably not possible with Grid. But it probably is possible with flexbox.